# Как качественно конвертировать цветной pdf-документ в черно-белый?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

Необходимо преобразовать цветной pdf-документ в чёрно-белый. Для этого я с помощью метода Render библиотеки PdfiumViewer получаю страницы документа в виде картинок с флагом PdfRenderFlags.Grayscale и заново их отрисовываю на тех же страницах с помощью XGraphics. Вот код данных действий:

```
try
{
    Image[] pagesAsImages;
    using (var document =
    PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load("input_document.pdf"))
    {
        pagesAsImages = new Image[document.PageCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < document.PageCount; i++)
        {
            pagesAsImages[i] = document.Render(i, 300, 300, PdfRenderFlags.Grayscale);
        }
    }

    PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
    using (PdfDocument inputDocument = PdfReader.Open("input_document.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < inputDocument.Pages.Count; i++)
        {
            PdfPage pdfPage = inputDocument.Pages[i];
            PdfPage editablePage = outputDocument.AddPage();
            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(editablePage);
            gfx.DrawImage(pagesAsImages[i], 0, 0, pdfPage.Width, pdfPage .Height);
        }
    }    
    outputDocument.Save("output_document.pdf");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // handle exceptions
}
```

Проблема в том, что отрисованная страница значительно теряет качество и становится мутной. И если отображение текста 14-го размера ещё более-менее удовлетворяет, то мелкий текст читается плохо. Скриншоты примеров страниц с мелким текстом приведены ниже.

[image: Часть страницы исходного документа]

[image: Часть страницы полученного документа]

Как я могу улучшить качество изображения?
Метод `Render(i, 300, 300, PdfRenderFlags.Grayscale);` принимает в качестве второго и третьего аргументов `dpiX` и `dpiY`. Пробовала менять эти значения, но не помогло. Изменение флагов `PdfRenderFlags` (`ForPrinting`, например, пробовала ставить) также ни к чему не ведёт. В этом проблема или в чём-то другом? Возможно, как-то отрисовывать можно по-другому? Либо же есть какой-то другой способ конвертировать цветной pdf в черно-белый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо использовать перегруженный метод Render, который принимает в качестве аргументов ещё и ширину, и высоту полученной картинки.

```
document.Render(i, 3508, 2480, 300, 300, PdfRenderFlags.Grayscale);
```

Почему именно 3508 и 2480? Об этом ниже.

При отрисовке качество картинок не портилось, они загружались изначально через метод Render в плохом качестве. Это проверила, когда сохранила картинки из массива `pagesAsImages[]`.

При загрузке картинок со страниц документа их разрешение выходило 595 × 841 пикселей при dpi = 300, при этом для листа A4 при таком значении количества точек на дюйм (300) разрешение должно быть 3508 × 2480, о чём прочитала на https://biznessystem.ru/kakoj-razmer-v-pikselyah-imeet-list-formata-a4/, скриншот ниже:

[image: Разрешение листа A4]

Спасибо всем, кто пытался найти решение)